# Replace first line in directory files

Tags: sed, makefile

I would like to execute this make command to first replace the first line of all csv files inside the directory and then replace the `@` for commas through the other lines.

The second command is working fine and does what it is supposed to do, but the first one only replaces the line on the first file.

Could anyone give me a help on that?

```
csv: 
    $(DOCKER_RUN) npm run csv-generator
    make format-csv

format-csv:
    @sed -i '' '1 s/^.*$$/"bar","repository"/g' $(CURDIR)/foo/npm/*.csv
    @sed -i '' 's/\(.*\)@/\1","/g' $(CURDIR)/foo/npm/*.csv
```

Comment: the command looks fine as is now

Comment: @fedorqui the second one works fine and changes all the files but the first changes only one file. The first one =/

Comment: I just tested it against some dummy files and it works well. So I cannot reproduce the error. Please add some [mcve] so we can help, otherwise it is something we cannot do much for.

Comment: Unless I misunderstand, your first `sed` command is explicitly restricted to line one: `'1s/source/target/g'`

Comment: @MichaelVehrs yes, line 1 of each file in that directory

Comment: `sed` counts the lines across **all** input files, unless you use the option `-i` or `-s`. Therefore, it will work only for the first line of the first file.

Comment: @MichaelVehrs I didn't get. I'm already using the -i flag

Comment: Sorry, I was confused. In that case, I suspect you are not using GNU `sed`, but something else, possibly BSD `sed`, which **always** counts across all files.

Comment: @MichaelVehrs: it's subtle, but the use of `sed -i '' …` indicates the use of BSD `sed`.  GNU `sed` uses just `-i` to edit 'in situ'.  BSD `sed` requires an extension, but that extension must be in a separate argument and may be an empty string.  The most nearly portable way to use `-i` is `-i.bak` with the extension attached to the `-i`.  That'll work with both BSD and GNU `sed` (but not necessarily on Solaris, AIX, HP-UX).

Comment: recursive make considered harmful aegis.sourceforge.net/auug97.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that the first `sed` command "fails" is that `sed` doesn't reset the line counter between input files (on your system, and neither on my Mac OS X machine, see comments):

```
$ cat test1
a
b
g

$ cat test2
aa
bb
cc

$ sed -n '=' test1 test2   # the '=' sed command outputs line numbers
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

This is why the first `sed` command isn't doing what you want it to do, it only affects the first file's first line.

The solution is to loop over the files and call `sed` for each of them (untested in Makefile):

```
@for f in $(CURDIR)/foo/npm/*.csv; do \
  sed -i '' '1 s/^.*$$/"bar","repository"/g' $f; \
done
```

Using `find` and `xargs` will also work, just make sure that `find` isn't picking up files further down in the folders.

**EDIT**:  In light of the comments on this answer, I would recommend avoiding the use of `sed -i` on multiple files altogether, and convert both statements into `for`-loops (in this case, they may be collapsed into one loop with two statements):

```
@for f in $(CURDIR)/foo/npm/*.csv; do \
  sed -i '' '1 s/^.*$$/"bar","repository"/g' $f; \
  sed -i '' 's/\(.*\)@/\1","/g' $f; \
done
```

In my experience, using `for`-loops in Makefiles seems to be far more common compared to using `find` and `xargs`. This is probably due to incompatibility between `find` and `xargs` versions between Unices. It also makes the Makefile a lot easier to read if one uses explicit loops.

Comment: 'Tis an interesting difference between BSD `sed` which is clearly being used by the OP and GNU `sed`.  GNU `sed` does reset the line numbers across files so that the operation on 'line 1' applies to line 1 of each file.  I wasn't aware of that, but it was easy to demonstrate on my Mac where I have both versions of `sed` installed.  Similarly, BSD `sed` treats an operation such as `sed '$s/.*/xyz/` *.csv` as changing only the last line of the last file, whereas GNU `sed` treats it as matching the last line of each file.  That at least is consistent.

Comment: Given the difference, it seems likely that one of the two variants is not conforming to POSIX, but what does POSIX say about [`sed()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sed.html)?  The answer is: _An address is either a decimal number that counts input lines cumulatively across files, a '$' character that addresses the last line of input, or …_  BSD `sed` implements this and GNU `sed` does not.  However, GNU `sed` only does this with the `-i` flag present (and the `-i` flag is not part of POSIX, so the standard no longer controls it). What GNU implements makes sense.

Comment: The situation is even less clear. According to the [FreeBSD 11](http://www.unix.com/man-page/FreeBSD/1/sed/) man page for `sed`, the option `-i` also resets the line count.

Comment: Your update is good.  I learned something more about `sed` as a result of this Q&A.  Unfortunately, I can only give one up vote.

Comment: @AlessandroResta My answer is updated. I believe that using an explicit `for`-loop is more portable and less error-prone than using `find` with `xargs`.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve with:

```
@find  $(CURDIR)/foo/npm -name "*.csv" -type f | xargs -L 1 sed -i '' '1 s/^.*$$/"bar"/g'
```

Comment: You don't need `xargs` here when you're executing the command once per file.  Use: `find $(CURDIR)/foo/npm -name ".csv" -type f -exec sed -i '' '1s/^.*$$/"bar"/g' {} \;` to run `sed` directly from `find`.  This has the side benefit of working correctly for file names containing spaces, etc.  (The `$$` is needed because `make` interprets that as `$`, of course.)